# Augmenting sitecore's media library

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc, sitecore-media-library

I am trying to find a way to augment sitecore's media library with media coming from an external source.

More specifically:
I want to create a button within the media library that if you click on it, you see a list of images that are provided at run time (via an API) and you can select on one of them in order to add it on a sitecore web page or an image field.

PS: I am new to sitecore programming, so as much as possible detailed information is highly appreciated; but also guidance.

Comment: This question will probably get closed as it breaks SO's guidelines. You will find more help here http://sitecore.stackexchange.com/ or on the Sitecore slack community http://sitecorechat.slack.com/

Comment: What @RichardSeal said.  Also, what you're trying to do is create a custom data provider.  It's probably the most complicated thing you can do in Sitecore as you will need supporting infrastructure all over the place.  It's not a job for someone 'new to Sitecore programming' I'm afraid.

Comment: Thank you both. I was also thinking about creating a data provider for my data. :)
@RichardHauer do you maybe know if I can use URLs for images without needing to copy them locally? I am using code from this post to create media items
http://sitecoreworld.blogspot.nl/2014/08/working-with-media-items.html
but through this I cannot use URIs correctly.  Do you know if I need to create a new field type for that?

Comment: You can, but you will need a custom MediaManager and/or LinkManager as well

Comment: Thanks so much @RichardHauer for the guidance, I managed to handle and image's url by creating a custom MediaProvider. :)